# struts2: ActionContext.getContext(); returns null

Tags: struts2, actioncontext

recently I updated my struts2 version from 2.0.11 to the current 2.2.3. 
Unfortunately I have curious problems now which I was not able to solve so far.

When I try to get the ActionContext:

```
ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();  
System.out.println("context: " + context);
```

The context is now null! The curious thing here is, that based on what the API says, it can't be null -> [getContext API desc](http://www.opensymphony.com/webwork/api/com/opensymphony/xwork/ActionContext.html#getContext%28%29)

It seems not to be a common problem, since I did not find one similar case via google.
Since I just have the problem after updating the struts2 version, I tried to exchange different librarys, but I did not get one step further.
Therefore I hope that someone of you can help me!

I have no more ideas what I can try to solve this problem.

Greetings
oetzi

.

EDIT1:

Hello umesh awasthi!
yes, it worked fine for quite a long time with the previous version. The log file unfortunately did not tell me much. Only that a NullpointerException occures when I try to access the ActionContext.getContext(); object.

This is an one code example where I use it

```
public CharServiceImpl(){  
    ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
    //currently it crashes here since the context variable is null
    Map<String,Object> appCon = context.getApplication();
    if (appCon != null){
        charIdsToUpdate = (ArrayList<Integer>) appCon.get("charIdsToUpdate");
    }
}
```

@Steven Benitez:
I am using the FilterDispatcher (However, I have to admit that I even did not know that there are different ones...)

By the way: I tried to log in during the last days over the function log in with stack exchange". I only get 3 "running points" but not a log in formular?!
Now I used my gmail account for it, which was not what I actually wanted to do, but I did not want to keep you waiting for my reaction.

Comment: if you fall back to previous version do you able to get instance of Actioncontext?? Also check the log files for any valuable information

Comment: can you also show where exactly you are using ActionContext

Comment: Which filter are you using for Struts: FilterDispatcher, StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter, something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I just edited my initial post

Answer (score 0):

Try creating ActionContext using ServletActionContext

```
class Abc implements ServletRequestAware
{
    HttpServletRequest request;
    public CharServiceImpl()
    {
      ActionContext actionContext =    ServletActionContext.getActionContext();
    }

   public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) 
   {
     this.request = request;
   }

    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() 
    {
      return this.request;
    }
}
```